# Find the business name associated with a street address with the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps Platform (Web JavaScript API), how do I find the business name associated with a street address?

I would expect PlacesService.textSearch() or PlacesService.findPlaceFromQuery() to return both "street_address" and "establishment" types when querying by an address associated with a business/establishment.  However, when I search by street address, I only receive "street_address" results.

For example, when searching "400 West Anderson Ln, Austin, Texas", I want to know that "Austin Parke Apartments" are at this address.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. geocode the address
2. use the places library `nearbySearch` to find places near that address
3. pick the closest result

```
var address = "400 West Anderson Ln, Austin, Texas";
geocoder.geocode({
  address: address
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status === 'OK') {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: results[0].geometry.location,
      zoom: 15
    });
    latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch({
      location: marker.getPosition(),
      rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
      types: ["establishment"]
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var marker = createMarker(results[i], i);
          if (i == 0)
            google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
        }
      } else {
        alert('nearbySearch was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a9xq8nv1/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infowindow;
var latLng;
var address = "400 West Anderson Ln, Austin, Texas";

function initMap() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: results[0].geometry.location,
        zoom: 15
      });
      latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
      console.log(results[0].geometry.location.toUrlValue(6))
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch({
        location: marker.getPosition(),
        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
        types: ["establishment"]
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          console.log(results.length + " results returned");
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var marker = createMarker(results[i], i);
            if (i == 0)
              google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
            else 
              marker.setMap(null);
          }
        } else {
          alert('nearbySearch was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  })
}

function createMarker(place, index) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name + "<br>" + address + "<br>" + index);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return marker;
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Google has changed their billing structure, and now caution against use of `nearbySearch` to locate a place from an address: . . . . . "By default, when a user selects a place, Nearby Search returns all of the available data fields for the selected place, and you will be billed accordingly. There is no way to constrain Nearby Search requests to only return specific fields. To keep from requesting (and paying for) data that you don't need, use a [Find Place](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) request instead." I imagine the answer's easily adapted.